# Pop up disappearing when screen rotates in ipad

Tags: ipad, bootstrap-modal

I am working on a website where I have used bootstrap modal. When I am testing my website in iPad, modal gets opened and working fine.But whenever i am trying to rotate the screen from portrait mode to landscape mode and touches the on modal, the modal disappears. Can any one tell me why this is happening?

Thanks..

Comment: check css Media Queries class file working properly regarding screen size

Comment: thanks Mr. MATH.h.  I checked and styles are working within the limits. Actually if i check in portrait mode only, it works fine same way if i am check only in landscape mode then also its working fine. The issue is coming only when i rotate the window after popup is displayed.

Comment: Would be interesting to see, which of the modal events are fired, especially `hidden.bs.modal`. https://gist.github.com/Simsso/6f1c46b432443aaf7d5b70d13418fcc4

Answer (score 0):

Use following code.

```js
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    $('.modal').stop()
               .animate({
                 'top': $(window).scrollTop()
               }, "fast");
});
```

```css
body.modal-open {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
}
```

I hope it will help. Please let me know your feedback on it.